# Find app id through secret key without logging in from facebook developer console

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, secret-key, app-id

Is there any API available for Facebook developer console which will provide APPID from SCRECT_KEY. Also is it possible that Facebook has deleted my app from the developer console? If yes where can I find whether my app is deleted or not.

Comment: Unclear what you are even referring to by “secret key”. If any of your apps were restricted or deleted, you should find them listed under https://developers.facebook.com/appeal

Comment: the link which you have provided show error message stating "Sorry, the link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed."

Comment: It doesn’t for me. Are you logged in to Facebook? Can you access the developer section at all?

Comment: I think so I found my solution, for redirecting to facebook page i am using https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={API_KEY}. Now that facebook has remove support for API_KEY. Now i need to provide APP ID.